# How do you use fully-specified types in arrays defined using shorthand form?

Tags: arrays, swift, syntax

According to the Swift documentation, the two means of defining an array are "functionally identical," but Xcode is giving me an error when I try to define an array like this:

```
private var tweets = [[Twitter.Tweet]]()
```

The error is:

> Cannot call value of non-function type '`[Array<Tweet.Type>]`'

And Xcode suggests deleting the trailing `()`. But both of the following are working fine:

```
private var tweets = [[Tweet]]()
private var tweets = [Array<Twitter.Tweet>]()
```

I need to fully specify the type as coming from the `Twitter` framework because I have just added a subclass of `NSManagedObject` called `Tweet` to work with `CoreData` in my project.

The Swift documentation says the shorthand form is preferred, so is there a way to use the shorthand form with a fully-specified type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3813) in the Swift compiler. There are several workarounds you can use until it's fixed:

1. Use a type annotation instead, with an empty array literal:

   ```
   private var tweets: [[Twitter.Tweet]] = []
   ```
2. Use a type alias:

   ```
   private typealias TwitterTweet = Twitter.Tweet 
   private var tweets = [[TwitterTweet]]()
   ```
3. Expand all the `[T]` syntactic sugar, and use `Array<T>` instead

   ```
   private var tweets = Array<Array<Twitter.Tweet>>()
   ```

Comment: Did you mean to use the type alias in that last line of code of the second workaround?

Comment: @John Nope, it's not necessary. The issue only comes from a combination with using `[T]()` as a shorthand for `Array<T>()`, ***and*** having `T` be a nested type. Resolving either will fix the issue.

Comment: @John `#1` resolves the issue by not calling the initializer with `()`, but using an empty array literal instead, `#2` resolves the issue by making `T` not a nested type (but rather, a non-nested type which aliases a nested type), and `#3` resolves the issue by not using `[T]` syntax at all. You can combine and of these 3 techniques and still have valid code

Comment: I still get the error with the second workaround unless I use the type alias like `private var tweets = [[TwitterTweet[]()`. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity as well as answering the question - it is a bit of a relief to find out it is a bug and not that I don't understand how to define arrays!

Comment: @John Ohhhh yes, that was typo, it should be `TwitterTweet`. The type alias would be rather ineffective if you end up not using it all! :p

Answer (score 1):

There is also some other way to prepare your array:

```
private var tweets: [[Twitter.Tweet]] = []
```

Full playground code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import CoreData

struct Twitter {

    class Tweet: NSManagedObject {
        //
    }
}

private var tweets: [[Twitter.Tweet]] = []
```